# Better sample questions for our tour

Tags: feature-request, scope

Today, we noticed that our tour page showed a question about **WooCommerce**, tagged `plugin-recommendation`. Well …

[image]

We can change the question and use one of a fixed list. But all questions in that list are actually not very good: too short, too broad or no research efforts.

I would like to use one of the following questions:

- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)
- [Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/adding-a-taxonomy-filter-to-admin-list-for-a-custom-post-type)
- [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)
- [Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)

I tried to hack the selection form, but that didn’t work. :D

**Update 15.01.2015**

I just selected [Should all plugins be encapsulated in a Class?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26186/should-all-plugins-be-encapsulated-in-a-class)
This wasn’t available earlier.

See also: [What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page)